# Futuristic thriller about Demolition Man-like future with cops using hitech tranquilizer guns

Tags: story-identification, movie

It's either from 2000s or 1990s. Snippets:

- cops using hitech tranquilizers (with propeller wings, IIRC) to make people unconscious instantly, to be followed by "ambulance chasing" lawyers
- an old-school retired cop surfing channels on TV, softporn everywhere, then finally getting to a restricted channel, entering the code, and getting a 1980s action movie
- a global surveillance system (called "God" or something like that?)
- the crime was about some kind of life extension or immortality (?)
- the investigators are a guy and a girl
- no A-level stars, but the acting was OK

I tried to look in IMDB, Wikipedia, and other sources using tags, plot, by the year, no luck.